# Will any user disable JavaScript in mobile browsers like iphone, android? even if device is capable?

Tags: javascript, accessibility, mobile-safari, mobile-website

On desktop websites we always think "what if the user has JavaScript disabled" and we try to make our code gracefully degradable so we can at least display the important info.

But in Mobile browsers should we think the same way? Is there any reason to disable javascript in mobile browsers? Are they any securtiy threats via JavaScript for mobile websites?

http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-enable-disable-JavaScript-on-the-Droid-Android-phone

[image]

Comment: @Greg - Thanks to improve my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course some security risk with JavaScript on mobile phones - if there wasn't, you could be sure that desktop browsers would have the same security!  But mobile users are perhaps more likely to have JavaScript on because - especially on the iPhone - it has to stand in for Flash or Silverlight functionality. JS is also used to provide faux-native interfac controls to Web apps, and thus has even more added value.

Of course, it is ideal to support users without JavaScript. If it is feasible you should absolutely strive to do so unless dynamic interactions are so integral to your service that you cannot so without.

Comment: OR if you're on a budget and are instructed to not waste time / resources on the very small percentage of users who disable JS ;)

Comment: thought I covered that with "if it is feasible!" yes, and furthermore users who disable JS really have no right to complain. funny old world we live in, though...

Comment: does anyone have any stats on users who disable JS in their mobiles?

Comment: I don't have smartphone-specific numbers.  In the United States, 2.06% of all users have JS disabled according to the Yahoo survey.  The number of those which are mobile phone users is likely lower still.